# Render pdf from other domain in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, cross-domain

I'm trying to render a PDF in my web page from another domain.

The html is:

```
<div id="pdfContainer">
    <embed id="pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$.get("http://otherDomain/Files/Pdf/some.pdf", function(data) {
    $("#pdf").prop("src", data);
});
```

But of course I have a cross domain error. Is there a way to do it? With PHP maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: Um, why not just point the `embed` to the external URL directly? `$("#pdf").prop("src", "http://otherDomain/Files/Pdf/some.pdf");`

Comment: Just remove the outer ajax function, you can't append all the data in the file to the src attribute anyway.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes this is the first thing I did but I got: `Origin http://domain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).`
@adeneo Then how to do?

Comment: `the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)` that's probably the first thing you should fix. An `embed` can have a cross-domain origin

Comment: I thought the 403 error was due to the cross domain problem. I will try to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `scr`-attribute of an `<embed>`-tag, it will really change the attribute, but it won't change the embedded object itself. I think the only ways to change or to make an already embedded object visible are:

```
// hide it in the beginning and show it on demand
$("#pdf").show();

// replace the whole node
$("#pdfContainer").html('<embed src="[URL]" type="application/pdf" />');
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/jN3G7/1/)